# CPU hungry android emulator : android ARM EABI image vs x86 image

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new android developer, 
I am currently using API-15 android image ARM EABI v7 
I was looking android sdk manager that there is another Intel x86 image for android API level 15

My machine is Intel Core i5 - 8GB RAM + Radeon 2GB dedicated graphics card

But my emulator takes alot of cpu .. When I run the emulator, the cpu fan throws alot of heat and constantly runs, cpu level for one of the cores goes pretty high.

Will using an x86 Image for android improve performance ?
Can I make it use the dedicated graphics gpu as well to improve efficiency ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  When I use x86 emulator on my early 2011 macbook pro, it runs my apps faster than a real device, such as a Nexus 7.  And when create the AVD, there is an option to use the GPU, or you can use a command argument to have it use the GPU.

Here's a screen shot of my ave definition...note the GPU emulation setting in the Hardware section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I will try and come back with my experience

Comment: I tried api-15 x86 image, reasonably faster than arm image and consuming relatively lower cpu as well. However the x86 image for api-10 only works without gpu. With Gpu enabled it shows up black screen and does not boot at all, any idea about that ?

Comment: For the api-10 x86 image, my experience is the similar to yours.  Never worried about it too much since I was able to use the api-15 version, and have devices at api-10 for testing.

Comment: Hi Bob, I am not able to configure x86 atom image with Google API-15 , just works with plain API-15. Did you managed to get it sorted somehow?

Comment: @Jane - The Google API-15 is not an x86 image, so it's not possible to configure it that way.  I use an AVD based on a Google API when testing licensing or in-app purchasing.  But otherwise use an API-15 x86 based AVD.

Answer (score 4):

It will be much faster. Remember to also set up HAXM for ultimate performance though. See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html for instructions!